# Improving really bad systems

Tags: refactoring, system

How would you begin improving on a really bad system?

Let me explain what I mean before you recommend creating unit tests and refactoring. I could use those techniques but that would be pointless in this case.

Actually the system is so broken it doesn't do what it needs to do.

For example the system should count how many messages it sends. It mostly works but in some cases it "forgets" to increase the value of the message counter. The problem is that so many other modules with their own workarounds build upon this counter that if I correct the counter the system as a whole would become worse than it is currently. The solution could be to modify all the modules and remove their own corrections, but with 150+ modules that would require so much coordination that I can not afford it.

Even worse, there are some problems that has workarounds not in the system itself, but in people's head. For example the system can not represent more than four related messages in one message group. Some services would require five messages grouped together. The accounting department knows about this limitation and every time they count the messages for these services, they count the message groups and multiply it by 5/4 to get the correct number of the messages. There is absolutely no documentation about these deviations and nobody knows how many such things are present in the system now.

So how would you begin working on improving this system? What strategy would you follow?

A few additional things: I'm a one-men-army working on this so it is not an acceptable answer to hire enough men and redesign/refactor the system. And in a few weeks or months I really should show some visible progression so it is not an option either to do the refactoring myself in a couple of years.

Some technical details: the system is written in Java and PHP but I don't think that really matters. There are two databases behind it, an Oracle and a PostgreSQL one. Besides the flaws mentioned before the code itself is smells too, it is really badly written and documented.

Additional info:

The counter issue is not a synchronization problem. The counter++ statements are added to some modules, and are not added to some other modules. A quick and dirty fix is to add them where they are missing. The long solution is to make it kind of an aspect for the modules that need it, making impossible to forget it later. I have no problems with fixing things like this, but if I would make this change I would break over 10 other modules.

Update:

I accepted Greg D's answer. Even if I like Adam Bellaire's more, it wouldn't help me to know what would be ideal to know. Thanks all for the answers.

Comment: Good luck!  There's one thing I like about working on a broken system-- nothing that I do to it can make it worse than it was before I started.  :)

Comment: +1 - This situation is so horribly awesome! or is it awesomely horrible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. **Put out the fires**.  If there are any issues of critical priority, whatever they are, you've got to handle them first.  Hack it in if you must, with a smelly codebase it's ok.  You know you'll improve it going forward.  This is your sales technique targeted at whomever you're reporting to.
2. **Pick some low-hanging fruit.**  I assume you're relatively new to this particular software and that you were re-tasked to deal with it.  Find some apparently easy problems in a related subsystem of the code that shouldn't take more than a day or two to resolve apiece, and fix them.  This may involve refactoring, or it may not.  The goal is to familiarize yourself with the system and with the style of the original author.  You may not get really lucky (One of the two incompetents who worked on my system before me always post-fixed his comments with four punctuation marks instead of one, which made it very easy to distinguish who wrote the particular segment of code.), but you'll develop insight into the author's weaknesses so you know what to look out for.  Extensive, tight coupling with global state vs poor understanding of language tools, for example.
3. **Set a big goal.**  If your experience parallels mine, you'll find yourself in a particular bit of spaghetti code more and more often as you perform the prior step.  This is the first knot you need to untangle.  With the experience you've gained understanding the component and knowledge about what the original author likely did wrong (and thus, what you need to watch out for), you can start envisioning a better model for this subset of the system.  Don't worry if you still have to maintain some messy interfaces to maintain functionality, just take it one step at a time.

Lather, rinse, repeat!  :)

Given time, consider adding unit tests for your new model one level underneath your interfaces with the rest of the system.  Don't engrave the bad interfaces in code via tests that use them, you'll be changing them in a future iteration.

Addressing the particular issues you mention:

When you run into a situation that users are working around manually, *talk with the users* about changing it.  Verify that they'll accept the change if you provide it before sinking the time into it.  If they don't want the change, your job is to maintain the broken behavior.

When you run into a buggy component that multiple other components have worked around, I espouse a parallel component technique.  Create a counter that works how the existing one *should* work.  Provide a similar (or, if practical, identical) interface and slide the new component into the codebase.  When you touch external components that work around the broken one, try to replace the old component with the new one.  Similar interfaces ease porting of the code, and the old component is still around if the new one fails.  Don't remove the old component until you can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My plan was/is to go for the low-hanging fruits first, the problem is that I just couldn't find one. Maybe I should try harder...

Comment: Fruit can be in the eye of the beholder.  I was lucky b/c my system was a couple of .Net winforms apps, so my initial low hanging fruit was fixing UI organization and hundreds of warnings about potential null references.

Answer (score 3):

What is being asked of you right now?  Are you being asked to implement functionality, or fix bugs?  Do they even know what they want you to do?

If you don't have the manpower, time, or resources to "fix" the system as a whole, then all you can do is bail water.  You're saying you should be able to make some "visible progress" in a few months' time.  Well, with the system being as bad as you described, you may actually make the system worse.  Under pressure to do something noticeable, you'll simply add code, and make the sysem even more convoluted.

You need to refactor, eventually.  There is no way around it.  If you can find a way to refactor that is visible to your end users, **that would be ideal**, even if it takes 6-9 months or a year instead of "a few months."  But if you can't, then you have a choice to make:

- Refactor, and risk being viewed as "not accomplishing anything" despite your efforts
- Don't refactor, accomplish "visible" goals, and make the system more convoluted and more difficult to refactor one day.  (Maybe after you find a better job, and hope the next developer to come along can never find out where you live.)

Which one is most beneficial to you personally depends on your company's culture.  Will they one day decide to hire more developers, or replace this system completely with some other product?

Conversely, if your efforts to "fix things" actually break other things, will they be understanding about the monstrosity you're being asked to tackle single-handedly?

No easy answers here, sorry.   You have to evaluate based on your unique, individual situation.

Comment: I never assume the customer know what he or she wants :-) However in this case I don't implement new functionality. The most important goal would be to make it possible to implement new things faster and easier.

Answer (score 2):

This is a whole book that will basically say unit test and refactor, but with more practical advice on how to do it

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51RCXGPXQ8L._SL500_AA240_.jpg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)

[http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)

Comment: Hmm, thanks added that to my amazon wishlist. Will get it with the next order :-)

Answer (score 1):

You open the directory that contains this system with Windows Explorer. Then, press Ctrl-A, and then Shift-Delete. That sounds like an improvement in your case.

Seriously though: that counter sounds like it's got thread-safety issues. I'd put a lock around the increasing functions.

And regarding the rest of the system, you can't do the impossible so try to do the possible. You need to attack your system from two fronts. Take care of the more visibly problematic issues first, so you can show progress. At the same time, you should deal with the more infrastructural problems, so that you have a chance at actually fixing this thing some day.

Good luck, and may the source be with you.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one area that would be of medium difficulty to refactor. Create a skeleton of the original code with only the method signatures of the existing ones; maybe use an Interface even. Then start hacking away. You can even point the "new" methods to the old ones until you get to them.

Then, testing, testing, testing. Since there aren't any unit tests, maybe just use good old fashioned Voice-Activated-Unit Tests (people)? Or write your own tests as you go.

Document your progress as you go in some kind of repository, including frustrations and questions, so that when the next poor schmuck who gets this project won't be where you are :).

Once you get the first part done, move on to the next. The key is to build on top of incremental progress, that's why you shouldn't start with the hardest part first; it'll be too easy to get demoralized.

Joel has a couple of articles on rewriting/refactoring:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000348.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right on the process, I have done it before. But in this system I just can not find the handle to pull first.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with a legacy system with the same characteristics for almost three years now, and there are no shortcuts that I'm aware of.

What bothers me most with our legacy system is that I'm not allowed to fix some bugs, since many other functions could break if I fixed them. This calls for ugly workarounds or creating new versions of old functions. Calls to the old functions can then be replaced with the new one at a time (while testing).

I'm not sure what the goal of your task is, but I strongly advise you to touch as little of the code as possible. Only do what you need to do.

You may want to get as much as possible documented by interviewing people. This is a huge task, since you don't know which questions to ask, and people will have forgotten a lot of details.

Other than that: make sure you're getting paid and enough moral support. There will be weeping and gnashing of teeth...

Comment: One of my colleagues tried to ask the original dev about our system to get some idea.  The only response he got was, "Everything you need to know is in the code."  That was before the original dev e-mailed me a zip file of his build directory b/c the source repository didn't build.

Comment: Yepp, sounds familiar. However I don't think I can just accept the answer to touch as little code as is possible and get the money for nothing. I might be too keen, but that simply is not my way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to start somewhere, and it sounds like there are bugs that need fixing. I would work through those bugs, making quick win refactorings, and writing any unit tests possible along the way. I would also use a tool like [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) to identify some of the most 'complex' parts of code in the system and see if I could simplify their design in any way. Ultimately, you just have to accept that it will be a slow process, and make small steps towards a better system.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to pick a part of the system that could be extracted and rewritten in isolation fairly quickly. Even if it doesn't do much, you could show progress pretty quickly, and you don't have the problem of interfacing with the legacy code directly.

Hopefully, if you could pick off a few such tasks, they will see you making visible progress, and you could put forward an argument for hiring more people to rewrite the bigger modules. When parts of the system rely on broken behaviour, you don't have much choice but to separate before you fix anything.

Hopefully, you could gradually build a team capable of rewriting the whole lot.

All of this would have to go hand in hand with some decent training, otherwise people's old habits will stick, and your work will get the blame when things don't work as expected.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Deprecate everything that currently exists that has problems, and write new ones that work correctly. Document as much as you can about what will change and put big red flashing signs all over the place pointing to this documentation.

By doing it that way, you can keep your existing bugs (the ones that are being compensated for somewhere else) around without slowing down your progress towards getting an actual working system.